# Fortify Scan - Possible Variable Overwrite: Global Scope

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli, overriding, fortify

We had Forify scan for our website code and fortify reported few issues. We are using **CodeIgniter 3.1.9 framework**. One of the issue they mentioned as

> Possible Variable Overwrite' for function 'extract()' in file mysqli_utility.php.

[image]

As this is core file of CI framework, I'm not using this function directly and also I do not know where this function getting used by CI.
Will you please help to resolve the issue reported by Fortify? What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

`extract()` imports variables from an array into the current symbol table. The phrase "*current symbol table*" basically means into the current scope of the code. For the usage in question, `extract()` is called inside a class method. So the current scope for the extracted vars will be in that method and that method only for that instance of the class.

CodeIgniter's core code does not define or use global variables. Unless code developed for the application uses globals (which it should not as "globals" are more of a "procedural programming" thing) the possibility of overwriting is exceedingly low.

I'm curious as to why the scan didn't pick up all the other times `extract` is used by CodeIgniter.